# Can the total sample size for the Pulse Survey results be included in blog posts?

Tags: feature-request, blog

I've noticed the [Pulse Survey](https://stackoverflow.blog/stackoverflowknows/) results on the Stack Overflow blog, and sometimes have wanted to share the interesting results with coworkers or stakeholders. However, I can't find the total sample size for these surveys. This information doesn't seem to be included in the posts or elsewhere. This is important basic information for readers to have to be able to understand survey results. If the population of people whose opinions we're interested in is basically all developers, then a [survey of 1000 individuals is very different from a survey of 100 individuals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1358082).

Can the blogging team start including the total sample size in these posts?